# Example 2, Sec 7 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY 2nd ed: How to show that $\mathbb{Z}_+ \times \mathbb{Z}_+$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

We need to show that there is a bijection $h \colon \mathbb{Z}_+ \times \mathbb{Z}_+ \to \mathbb{Z}_+$. For this purpose, Munkres define a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{Z}_+ \times \mathbb{Z}_+$ as follows: 
$$A \colon= \{ \ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \times \mathbb{Z}_+ \ \colon \ y \leq x \ \}.$$
Then he defines the maps $f \colon \mathbb{Z}_+ \times \mathbb{Z}_+ \to A$ and $g \colon A \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ as follows: 
$$f(x,y) \colon= (x+y-1, y) \ \ \ \forall \ \  (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \times \mathbb{Z}_+,$$
and 
$$g(x,y) \colon= \frac{(x-1)x}{2} + y \ \ \ \forall \ \ (x,y) \in A.$$
That the map $f$ is a bijection is clear to me.

How to show (directly) that the map $g$ is also a bijection?

It is clear intuitively.

Once we show that $g$ is indeed a bijection, then the map $h$ could be defined as $$h \colon= g \circ f.$$

My effort:

For all $(x,y) \in A$, we note that 
$$g(x,y) = y+ \sum_{i=1}^{x-1} i.$$

What next?

Comment: You actually just need to show there exists an injection going in each direction to get the existence of a bijection,  and one direction here is trivial :)

Comment: If $x=1$, what would the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{x-1} i$ happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked me to answer here: http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-1/section-7-countable-and-uncountable-sets/#comment-2337405063.

To formally see that $g$ is bijective, note that

a) for every $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, $g((x,y))\in\mathbb {Z}_+$;

b) $g((1,1))=1$;

c) if $y<x$ then $g(x,y)+1=g((x,y+1))$; and

d) for every $x\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, $g(x,x)+1=g((x+1,1))$.

a)-d) show that the image set of $g$ is an inductive subset of $\mathbb{Z}_+$, i.e. it is $\mathbb{Z}_+$, and $g$ is surjective. They also show that $g$ is injective, as for $x<x'$ and $y<y'$, $g(x,y)<g(x,y')<g(x',1)$.

Comment: your proof of surjectivity of the map $g$ is beautiful! But you might wanna revise your proof of the injectivity of $g$. At least I haven't been able to make sense of it.

Comment: how do you regard this proof? Suppose $(x,y)$, $(x^\prime, y^\prime)$ are two distinct points of $A$. Suppose first that $x = x^\prime$ and $y < y^\prime$. Then $$g(x,y) < g(x,y^\prime).$$ Next suppose that $x < x^\prime$. Then $x+1 \leq x^\prime$ and so  $$g(x,y) \leq g(x,x) = \frac{x(x+1)}{2} \leq \frac{x^\prime(x^\prime - 1)}{2} < g(x^\prime, y^\prime).$$

Comment: The proof is there, if $y<y'$ then $g(x,y)<g(x,y')$ (using c), and if $x<x'$ then $g(x,y)<g(x+1,1)<\ldots<g(x',1)\le g(x',y'')$ (using d). This is what I meant. Besides, the answer you selected does not answer your question. There are many ways to show there is a bijection of $\mathbb{Z}_+\times \mathbb{Z}_+$ with $\mathbb{Z}_+$. But your question asked about the specific way Munkres uses in his book.

Comment: you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

This works, but (in my opinion) there's an easier way to show countability: given a pair of positive integers $a, b$, let $h(a, b)=2^a(2b+1)$ - that is, the $a$th power of 2 times the $b$th odd number. This is a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+$ to $\mathbb{Z}_+$.

- Surjectivity: Given $c\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, let $a$ be the largest power of 2 which divides $c$, and let $k={c\over 2^a}$. Then $k$ is odd, so $k=2b+1$ for some $b$; then $c=h(a, b)$.
- Injectivity: Given $a, a', b, b'\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, if $h(a, b)=h(a', b')$, then we must have $a=a'$; otherwise, suppose $a<a'$, then $2b+1=2^{a'-a}(2b+1)$, which is a contradiction since $2b+1$ is odd but $a'-a>0$. But if $a=a'$, then $b=b'$ after dividing both sides by $2^a$.

Comment: I think the correct formula for a surjective map $h \colon \mathbb{Z}_+ \times \mathbb{Z}_+ \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ would be as follows: $$h(m,n) \colon= 2^{m-1}(2n-1) \ \mbox{ for all } \ (m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \times \mathbb{Z}_+.$$ Don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Your observation that
$$g(x,y) = y+\sum_{i=1}^{x-1}i$$
is good.

Define $T(x) = \sum_{i=1}^x i$ to be the $x$'th triangular number. The question is then if any integer $z\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ can be written uniquely as the sum of a triangular number $T(x-1)$ and an integer $y\leq x$.

That $g$ is surjective is clear: Let $z\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, choose $x$ with $T(x-1)<z\leq T(x)$, and set $y = z-T(x-1)$. Since $T(x)-T(x-1) = x$, and since $z\leq T(x)$, we have $y\leq x$. Also,
$$z = y + T(x-1).$$
Now it also makes intuitively sense that this decomposition is unique: Take the largest triangular number $T(x-1)$ strictly less than $z$, and let $y$ be the remaining part.
As for a more rigorous argument for uniqueness, suppose that
$$ z = y_1+T(x_1-1),$$
$$ z = y_2+T(x_2-1),$$
where $y_1\leq x_1$ and $y_2\leq x_2$, and suppose further for contradiction that $x_1<x_2$.
Then
$$T(x_2-1) - T(x_1-1) = y_1-y_2,$$
but $T(x_2-1)-T(x_1-1) = (x_2-1)+\cdots+x_1$, and since $y_1\leq x_1$, we must have
$$(x_2-1)+\cdots+x_1 = y_1-y_2<x_1,$$
which is a contradiction.