# Surjectivity of an $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$ function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(This is my first post on here - let me know if I need to edit anything.)

I'm just starting an introductory topology course and I've come across a problem that I've been trying to solve for a few hours now. I'm supposed to prove the bijectivity of the $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ function $f(i,j)=i+\frac{(i+j-2)(i+j-1)}{2}$.

Most of my struggle is coming from proving that the function is onto. I understand that I need to find an $i$ and $j$ so that $f(i,j)=z$ $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{N}$, but I'm having a hard time finding definitions of $i$ and $j$ that don't depend on each other.

And I have a start to a proof of one-to-one, where I started with $f(i,j)=f(h,k)$ and pretty much factored and simplified down to $(i+j)^2-i-3j=(h+k)^2-h-3k$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

I think I'm mainly having conceptual problems because the last time I did this sort of proof was in my discrete math course, which was much lower-level. All that aside, any hints would help immensely :)

Comment: what a weird topology course.

Comment: Of possible interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490324/defining-bijective-function-f-mathbbn-times-mathbb-n-to-mathbb-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507507/example-2-sec-7-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-how-to-show-that-mathbbz-ti and probably several others.

Comment: Have you had a look at those links, mathboy?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Surjectivity: Let $i+j-1=k.$ Then $k$ can be any integer greater than or equal to $ i.$ For a given $k,$ and for $1\leq i\leq k$, the function takes all the values from $1+(k^2-k)/2$ to $k+(k^2-k)/2=(k^2+k)/2.$  And for $k+1$ and  for $1\leq i\leq k+1$ the function takes all the values from $1+(k^2+k)/2$ to $k+1+(k^2+k)/2=((k+1)^2+(k+1))/2$.... ETC.

Comment: The idea behind this is to enumerate $\mathbb N^2$ as $(0,0), (1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(3,0),(2,1),(1,2),(0,3),...$ where we list those $(m,n)$ with the same $V=m+n$ by decreasing $m,$ starting with $V=0,$ then $V=1,$ etc. The point is that if $A$ is countably infinite then so is $A\times A$.

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary to modify the function since it is one-to-one and onto as proposed.

Show that $f(i,j)=i+\dfrac{(i+j-2)(i+j-1)}{2}$ is one-to-one and onto from $\mathbb{N}^2\,\to\,\mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$

The onto part is fairly simple since $\left\{\dfrac{(k-2)(k-1)}{2}\right\}_{k=2}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence in $\mathbb{N}\backslash \{1\}$ but achieves a minimum value of $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ when $k=1$ and $k=2$.

$$0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,66,78,\cdots$$

For each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ define ${\langle m \rangle}=\max\left\{k:\frac{(k-2)(k-1)}{2}<m\right\}$ and let $i=m-\dfrac{({\langle m \rangle}-2)({\langle m \rangle}-1)}{2}$ and let $i+j={\langle m \rangle}$.

Then $f(i,j)=i+\dfrac{(i+j-2)(i+j-1)}{2}=i+\dfrac{({\langle m \rangle}-2)({\langle m \rangle}-1)}{2} =m$ 
Using this we can see that, for example

1. $f(1,1)=1$
2. $f(1,2)=2$
3. $f(2,1)=3$
4. $f(1,3)=4$

Or we can skip ahead and see that for $m=25$, ${\langle m \rangle}=8$ since $\frac{(8-2)(8-1)}{2}=21$ is the largest value of $\frac{(k-2)(k-1)}{2}$ smaller than $25$. So $i=25-21=4$ and $j={\langle m \rangle}-i=8-4=4$. Thus $f(4,4)=25$.

But what if, in the case of $m=25$ rather than letting $i+j={\langle m \rangle}=8$ we let $i+j={\langle m \rangle}-1=7$. Then $i=25-\frac{(7-2)(7-1)}{2}=10$  And since $i+j=7$ then$j=-3$ which is not in $\mathbb{N}$.

To show that the function $f$ is one-to-one it would be necessary to show that for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ if $i+j={\langle m \rangle}-p$ for some $p<{\langle m \rangle}-1$ where $i=m-\dfrac{({\langle m \rangle}-p-2)({\langle m \rangle}-p-1)}{2}$then it would be the case that $j\le0$. This is in fact the case.

Let 
\begin{eqnarray}
j&=&{\langle m \rangle}-p+\frac{({\langle m \rangle}-p-2)({\langle m \rangle}-p-1)}{2}-m\text{ for }1\le p\le {\langle m \rangle}-2\\
&=&{\langle m \rangle}-p+\frac{({\langle m \rangle}-2-p)({\langle m \rangle}-1-p)}{2}-m\\
&=&\frac{({\langle m \rangle}-2)({\langle m \rangle}-1)}{2}+\frac{p^2-p(2{\langle m \rangle}-1)}{2}-m
\end{eqnarray}

Since this must be positive and since $\dfrac{({\langle m \rangle}-2)({\langle m \rangle}-1)}{2}-m<0$ then $\dfrac{p^2-p(2{\langle m \rangle}-1)}{2}$ must be positive for all values of $p$ in the interval $[1,{\langle m \rangle}-1]$. However, that is not the case since $\dfrac{p^2-p(2{\langle m \rangle}-1)}{2}\le0$ for every $p\in[0,2{\langle m \rangle}-1]$. So $j\le0$.

Thus $f$ is one-to-one and onto.

For $m\in\mathbb{N}$,

\begin{eqnarray}
f^{-1}(m)=\left(m-\langle m\rangle,\frac{3+\sqrt{1+8\langle m \rangle}}{2}-(m-\langle m \rangle)\right)
\end{eqnarray}

For example, find $f^{-1}(53)$.

$\langle 53\rangle=45$ so $i=53-45=8$ and $j=\dfrac{3+\sqrt{1+8(45)}}{2}-8=3$ so $f^{-1}(53)=(8,3)$ which can be verified by substitution back into $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are using in incorrect, because it leads to $f(0,0)=f(1,0)=1$, so that $f$ is not injective.

You could replace it by the following :

$$f:\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N},(i,j)\mapsto \frac{(i+j)(i+j+1)}{2}+j$$

Here is a proof for the surjectivity of the modified function :

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider :

$$N=\max\left\{k\in\mathbb{N};\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\le N\right\}$$

$N$ is well defined because $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=+\infty$

By definition of $N$ whe have :

$$\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\le n<\frac{(N+1)(N+2)}{2}$$

Now consider :

$$q=n-\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad p=N-q$$

It is clear that $q\ge0$. And we have also :

$$p=N-\left(n-\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\right)=\frac{N^2+3N}{2}-n=\frac{(N+1)(N+2)}{2}-n-1\ge0$$

so that $(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ and $f(p,q)=n$.

Comment: The symbol $\mathbb{N}$ is not always used consistently. Depending on the context, it can denote $\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ or $\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ In this problem I suspect it means  the latter, else both $f(k,1-k)=f(k,2-k)=k$ yield solutions for $k=0,1$.

Comment: I believe my text is using $\mathbb{N}$ to mean {1, 2, 3, ...}. They are defining it as the set of positive integers, at least. 
And to Adren, thanks! Wow, I never even thought to check that the function actually WAS bijective. I need to get out of the habit of blindly listening to a textbook... I see that with more complicated functions you have to get a little more creative. I'm used to just finding the inverse, but that seems to only work consistently with single-variable functions.